# OpenVAS on CentOS7 Redis won't start

Tags: centos, redis, openvas

I am trying to get OpenVAS working per the the article below.

https://www.atlantic.net/community/howto/install-openvas-vulnerability-scanner-centos-7

However it isn't working, when I run openvas-check-setup I get this error below and when I check /var/log/redis/redis.log it says "Opening Unix socket: bind: Permission denied"

```
openvas-check-setup 2.3.7   Test completeness and readiness of OpenVAS-8   (add '--v6' or '--v7' or '--v9'    if you want to check for another OpenVAS version)

  Please report us any non-detected problems and   help us to improve this check routine:   http://lists.wald.intevation.org/mailman/listinfo/openvas-discuss

  Send us the log-file (/tmp/openvas-check-setup.log) to help analyze the problem.

  Use the parameter --server to skip checks for client tools   like GSD and OpenVAS-CLI.

Step 1: Checking OpenVAS Scanner ...
        OK: OpenVAS Scanner is present in version 5.0.7.
        OK: OpenVAS Scanner CA Certificate is present as /var/lib/openvas/CA/cacert.pem.
        OK: redis-server is present in version v=3.0.7.
        OK: scanner (kb_location setting) is configured properly using the redis-server socket: /tmp/redis.sock
        ERROR: redis-server is not running or not listening on socket: /tmp/redis.sock
        FIX: You should start the redis-server or configure it to listen on socket: /tmp/redis.sock

 ERROR: Your OpenVAS-8 installation is not yet complete!
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because errors and omissions in tutorials should be referred to their author so they can be corrected.

Comment: @Hanginoninquietdesperation There's really no way the user could have known the tutorial was flawed. Worse, the upstream has sort of endorsed it.

Comment: If you follow a tutorial and it does not work, it is by definition flawed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Congratulations, you've found a bad Internet tutorial. It appears that the author of that tutorial never actually tested it himself to see if it works, because it doesn't work as-is. Worse, it appears that that tutorial is actually linked to from the official OpenVAS web site, which is going to mislead and frustrate a lot of people.

So, the reason redis is failing to start is because SELinux denies redis-server to write to `/tmp`. You can see this in your audit logs:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1482284806.464:112): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=1275 comm="redis-server" name="tmp" dev="dm-0" ino=33574981 scontext=system_u:system_r:redis_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:tmp_t:s0 tclass=dir
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1482284806.464:112): arch=c000003e syscall=49 success=no exit=-13 a0=5 a1=7ffe55938670 a2=6e a3=7ffe55938614 items=0 ppid=1 pid=1275 auid=4294967295 uid=997 gid=995 euid=997 suid=997 fsuid=997 egid=995 sgid=995 fsgid=995 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="redis-server" exe="/usr/bin/redis-server" subj=system_u:system_r:redis_t:s0 key=(null)
```

Rather than `/tmp`, the socket file should be located in `/run/redis`, for instance:

```
unixsocket /run/redis/redis.sock
```

This allows it to operate within the constraints SELinux imposes.

While editing `/etc/redis.conf`, be sure to check the bottom of the file for a *second* `unixsocket` directive that got added by `openvas-setup` and remove it as redundant.

Of course, generally on SELinux enabled systems, redis should be configured to listen to a TCP port on localhost, rather than using a socket, as other daemons might not be allowed to communicate with redis via a socket, but only via TCP. This isn't really an issue here as OpenVAS isn't (yet) SELinux-confined, but it also doesn't support contacting redis via TCP. The result of this is that this redis installation cannot be shared or reused with any other services than the local copy of OpenVAS.

---

But there's more than that wrong with this tutorial!

The second thing is that nowhere in it does OpenVAS ever get configured to actually use redis. It relies on the compiled in default, which as we have seen is wrong. To fix this requires [setting a configuration directive](https://fossies.org/linux/openvas-scanner/doc/redis_config.txt) in `/etc/openvas/openvassd.conf`, something which the tutorial never mentions:

```
kb_location = /run/redis/redis.sock
```

The *third* thing is that it uses a third party repo called atomic, which provides packages that conflict with packages in normal repos such as EPEL - which already provides redis and OpenVAS! It's not clear why atomic have done this, nor why this tutorial uses atomic to begin with. Using repositories with conflicting packages is potentially dangerous. If you continue with using atomic packages, you will need to be absolutely certain that this (virtual) machine is never used for *anything* else for any reason whatsoever.

Finally, once you get it installed, the web interface isn't actually reachable because the indicated port isn't open in the firewall. You also have to do this yourself.

```
firewall-cmd --add-port=9392/tcp    # though this opens it to the world
firewall-cmd --runtime-to-permanent
```

---

Once you're done, `openvas-check-setup` should say, among other things...

```
        OK: scanner (kb_location setting) is configured properly using the redis-server socket: /run/redis/redis.sock
        OK: redis-server is running and listening on socket: /run/redis/redis.sock.
        OK: redis-server configuration is OK and redis-server is running.
```

The irony is that it will then also say:

```
        ERROR: SELinux is enabled. For a working OpenVAS installation you need to disable it.
        FIX: Please disable SELinux.
```

Which appears to be completely gratuitous and unnecessary, as OpenVAS doesn't run confined by SELinux anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue. The problem was that on Kali Linux OpenVas do not have file: /etc/openvas/openvassd.conf by default.

So I create this file and entered below content to overwrite the default value for Redis Server.
kb_location=/var/run/redis/redis.sock

This fixed my issue.
I have wrote complete tutorial on this site: 
https://waqasahmedkhan.com/openvas-bug-in-kali-linux-2017-3-5/

Comment: Nice blog post!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for install OpenVAS on Kali Linux.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyrLx.png)

Do all commands in **ROOT** !

My solution:

```
 1. apt-get purge --auto-remove redis*

 2. apt-get install openvas

 3. apt-get install redis

 4. In these files /etc/redis/redis.conf && /etc/redis/redis-openvas.conf, you change et uncheck these parameters : 

    bind 127.0.0.0.1 ::1 => bind 0.0.0.0

    unixsocket run/redis.sock (OR) unixsocket /var/run/redis-openvas/redis-server.sock  => unixsocket /var/run/redis/redis.sock

    unixsocketperm 700 => unixsocketperm 770

 5. In this file /etc/openvas/openvas.conf, you change this parameter :
    
    db_address = /var/run/redis-openvas/redis-server.sock => db_address = /var/run/redis/redis.sock

 6. systemctl daemon-reload

 7. systemctl restart redis-server.service

 8. gvm-setup

 9. gvm-check-setup
```

It worked for me, good luck !

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sZRN.png)